# Tomcat - Context initialization failed

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am using Spring STS and Spring Roo. I am using [this](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-roo-spring-data-jpa-eclipse-integration/) tutorial to reverse engineer database. But when I try to run on server(Pivotal tc server, which is a tomcat server) I am getting following error.

```
       2015-06-23 11:37:48,509 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subhransu.mishra/Desktop/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE/tomcat-8.0.20.B.RELEASE/lib/tcServer3.jar!/com/springsource/tcserver/oracle/OracleDataSourceWrapper.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSourceFactory.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    Offending resource: file [C:\Users\subhransu.mishra\Desktop\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\GOPHERGUI\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext-jpa.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subhransu.mishra/Desktop/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE/tomcat-8.0.20.B.RELEASE/lib/tcServer3.jar!/com/springsource/tcserver/oracle/OracleDataSourceWrapper.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSourceFactory.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subhransu.mishra/Desktop/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE/tomcat-8.0.20.B.RELEASE/lib/tcServer3.jar!/com/springsource/tcserver/oracle/OracleDataSourceWrapper.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSourceFactory.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getCandidates(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:68)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:53)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:69)
        ... 34 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSourceFactory.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

POM file:(Updated: Added ojdbc, updated mysql driver to 5.1.35)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>GOPHERWEB</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GOPHERWEB</name>
    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.1</aspectj.version>
        <java.version>7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <roo.version>1.3.1.RC1</roo.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>codelds</id>
      <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
    </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
            <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
            <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- General dependencies for standard applications -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ROO dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${roo.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-js-resources</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <!-- <configuration> <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml> </configuration> -->
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>dbre.xml</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <!--
                      Aspects in src/main/java and src/main/aspects are added as default in the 
                      compile goal.
                      Aspects in src/test/java and src/test/aspects are added as default in the 
                      test-compile goal.
                      Aspects in src/main/java are added in the test-compile goal 
                      if weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder is set to true
                    -->
                    <weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>false</weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- IDE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                                <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <dependenciesAsLibraries>true</dependenciesAsLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the following two properties for JBoss only -->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" /-->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" /-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Update**

New error after adding ojdbc maven dependency. Now its showing mysql error. but mysql dependency is there.

```
2015-06-30 13:15:11,216 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subhransu.mishra/Downloads/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/GOPHERWEB/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar!/com/mysql/fabric/hibernate/FabricMultiTenantConnectionProvider.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/MultiTenantConnectionProvider.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Offending resource: file [C:\Users\subhransu.mishra\Downloads\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\GOPHERWEB\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext-jpa.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subhransu.mishra/Downloads/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/GOPHERWEB/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar!/com/mysql/fabric/hibernate/FabricMultiTenantConnectionProvider.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/MultiTenantConnectionProvider.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: The error complains about a missing oracle class, which is part of the Oracle JDBC driver. I don't see any dependency on the oracle JDBC driver in your pom.

Comment: But I specified mysql, `persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MYSQL ` . and also provided location of mysql driver. Should I still add oracle dependancy?

Comment: Apparently, a class of tcServer is scanned and relies on this class.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. But now it has a new error, related to mysql? Please check the Update section.

Comment: it seems to be a version mismatch: the error message suggests 5.1.35 is expected, but in the pom 5.1.18 is specified

Comment: I did not updated the pom file here. I have updated mysql connector from 18 to 35. Please check the updated pom file. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting FileNotFoundException because its not in your classpath. Please check the jar(specifically this class in your jar's packages) in your classpath and try switching to the latest version of mysql-connector.jar. It could be the compatibility issue between mysql-connector and hibernate jars.

Comment: Hi, updated mysql connector but did not update pom file here. sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been solved in "5.1.30" version of mysql jar. Checkout the Link:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,612977,612977

You need to upgrade the mysql-coonector jar version in pom.

Please note, this should have been a supporting comment to "Taoufik Mohdit", but I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 3):

The class *com.mysql.fabric.hibernate.FabricMultiTenantConnectionProvider* in *mysql-connector* jar uses *org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider* interface from *hibernate-core* jar, which is not under the right package in version 4.3.6.Final (it is there but under a different package: org.hibernate.**engine**.jdbc.connections.spi). *hibernate-core* version 4.3.9.Final has this class in the right package (org.hibernate.**service**.jdbc.connections.spi).

So in summary, if you upgrade hibernate-core to 4.3.9.Final, this should hopefully fix the problem.